# Wordpress: How to get posts_per_page from query_var?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to find the posts per page.

When I var_dump `$wp_query->query_vars`, I can see `['posts_per_page']=>int(4)`, but when I try to call for posts_per_page I get NULL.

Here are my codes:

```
$test = $wp_query->query_vars;  
var_dump($test->posts_per_page);
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why did someone vote this question down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `$wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];`

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I had to call `$wp_query->post_count` instead of posts_per_page.

Comment: `post_count` will return you the number of posts you got back from the query, and it's not necessarily equal to `posts_per_page`. If you have specified `posts_per_page` to `20` and you have only `10` posts matching, your `post_count` will return `10`.